# Create dynamic submenu + event triggering with append?

Tags: jquery

so I was trying to implement a submenu within a submenu on a navigation bar. The idea is to have the submenu "**reports management**" generates when the **Report** is clicked. The code as below.

**HTML**

```
         <li class="drop-down"><a href="#" id="btnFileMgmt">File &nbsp; <i class="icofont-document-folder"></i></a>
          <ul id="filesMgmt">
              
          </ul>
        </li>
```

**JQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){


      var files_management = '<li><a href="#" id="btnViewFiles">View Files</a></li>' + 
                             '<li class="drop-down"><a href="#" id="btnReports"> Reports </a>' + 
                                '<ul id="reportsMgmt">' + 
                                '</ul>' +
                             '</li>';

      var reports_management = '<li><a href="#" id="fileList">Files</a></li>' + 
                               '<li><a href="#" id="borrowList">Borrowed Files</a></li>';


      $("#btnFileMgmt").click(function(){
          $("#filesMgmt").append(files_management);
      });

      $("#btnReports").click(function(){
          $("#reportsMgmt").append(reports_management);
      });
```

But I don't understand is it the limitation or the way I using is wrong because it wouldn't generate when the **Reports** inside the **Files** is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach an event listener to you dynamically appended element.

For second click `#btnReports` you need to bind this click to the document event listener instead a `.click` function because `#btnReports` **does not** exist when we load the page. It append after we click on `#btnFileMgmt`

Also, Its ideal to use `.html` instead of an `.append` - `.html` will replace the previous elements and will not copy them. `.append` will **create elements** **multiple** time on every click you do.

Read more about how `.append` works [here](https://api.jquery.com/append/) and about `.html` [here](https://api.jquery.com/html/)

**Working Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/usmanmunir/w781s4ca/

Run snippet below to see it working

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var files_management = '<li><a href="#" id="btnViewFiles">View Files</a></li>' +
    '<li class="drop-down"><a href="#" id="btnReports"> Reports </a>' +
    '<ul id="reportsMgmt">' +
    '</ul>' +
    '</li>';

  var reports_management = '<li><a href="#" id="fileList">Files</a></li>' +
    '<li><a href="#" id="borrowList">Borrowed Files</a></li>';

  $("#btnFileMgmt").click(function() {
    $('#filesMgmt').html(files_management);
  });

  $(document).on("click", "#btnReports", function() {
    $('#reportsMgmt').html(reports_management);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="drop-down"><a href="#" id="btnFileMgmt">File &nbsp; <i class="icofont-document-folder"></i></a>

  <ul id="filesMgmt">

  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works. If possible, can you explain a little bit more because I'm new with jquery. Whats the difference between the html and append? also click and on? Many thanks

Comment: Glad i was able to help you. Do not forget to up-vote my answer as if it helped you. Let me edit my answer. I  will add some link to where you read about the `.append` and `.html`